# Difference between Fate/Stay Night and Fate/Stay Night UBW?

Tags: fate-stay-night

I'm quite confused and I'd like to know what's the difference between **Fate/Stay Night** and **Fate/Stay Night Unlimited Blade Works**?

Comment: Related: [What is the viewing order of fate related works](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/what-is-the-viewing-order-of-fate-related-works/12842#12842)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by senshin in his answer to the question [What is the viewing order of Fate-related works?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/what-is-the-viewing-order-of-fate-related-works/12835#12835)

- [*Fate/stay night*](https://vndb.org/v11) is a visual novel originally released in 2004. The story has three routes: **Fate**, **Unlimited Blade Works**, and **Heaven's Feel**.
- The first TV anime series by DEEN in 2006, titled [*Fate/stay night*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/356/Fate/stay_night), mostly adapted the **Fate** route.

  > However, Caster's plan to prematurely summon the Grail was taken from the **Unlimited Blade Works** route, and Sakura and Rin's fight was taken from the **Heaven's Feel** route
- The movie by DEEN in 2010, titled [*Fate/stay night: Unlimited Blade Works*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6922/Fate/stay_night:_Unlimited_Blade_Works), adapted a highly condensed form of the **Unlimited Blade Works** route.
- The second TV anime series by Ufotable in [Fall 2014](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22297/Fate/stay_night:_Unlimited_Blade_Works_(TV)) and [Spring 2015](http://myanimelist.net/anime/28701/Fate/stay_night:_Unlimited_Blade_Works_(TV)_2nd_Season), also titled [*Fate/stay night: Unlimited Blade Works*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22297/Fate/stay_night:_Unlimited_Blade_Works_(TV)), is another adaptation of the **Unlimited Blade Works** route.
- There are plans for [a movie/series of movies](http://myanimelist.net/anime/25537/Fate/stay_night:_Heavens_Feel) by Ufotable which adapts **Heaven's Feel** route.