# Is Fate/Apocrypha sequel of Unlimited Blade Works?

Tags: fate-series

I want to watch Fate/Apocrypha but I didn't watch Unlimited Blade Works. So, is Fate/Apocrypha the sequel to Unlimited Blade Works?

Comment: Related: [Fate viewing order](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12835/1458)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34662/Fate_Apocrypha) page, Fate/Apocrypha is set in a parallel world to the Fate/stay night series.

(First sentence of the synopsis):

> The setting is a parallel world to Fate/stay night where the Greater Grail mysteriously disappeared from Fuyuki after the Third Holy Grail War.

You only need to have watched the original series, in this case. Apocrypha is not particularly important to the series.

(Also see [Senshin's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12835/1458) for the full order)

Comment: i would argue Apocrypha's importance to the world building of the Nasuverse given what gets revealed in the novel (assuming the anime wont deviate) and that it is Apocrypha which confirmed Mordred being female like that of her "Father" which was only guessed at by Studio Deen. also there's Jackie